# Merging two unequal length dfs with matching subset of index

Tags: python, pandas

**Description:**
I have two data frames `foreign` (having options in English and its Urdu translation) and `native`,having `German version of options`, **Lengths of both DFs is unequal** the `native` is much bigger than `foreign` and carries complete list of options. I want to **merge** them two using `idx` column so that `native` df searches for each entry in its `idx` in the `foreign`; if `idx` is matching than its adds two `columns` namely: `option_eng` and `option_urdu` otherwise fill it with `NAN`

```py
I have two dataframs
foreign:
idx                    option_eng                    option_urdu
1.1.01-001   This is english of option1             urdu translation of option1
1.1.01-001   This is english of option2             urdu translation of option2
1.1.01-001   This is english of option3             urdu translation of option3 
1.1.01-002   This is english of option1             urdu translation of option1
1.1.01-002   This is english of option2             urdu translation of option2
1.1.01-002   This is english of option3              Urdu translation of option3
1.1.01-003   This is english of option1              urdu translation of option1
1.1.01-003   This is english of option2              urdu translation of option2
1.1.01-004   This is english of option1              urdu translation of option1
1.1.01-004   This is english of option2               urdu translation of option2

Native:>> a unequal to df1
  idx    sort_code  iscorrect   count                option_de
1.1.01-001  1          1          1              German tranlation option3
1.1.01-001  2          1          2              German tranlation option2
1.1.01-001  3          0          3              German tranlation option1
1.1.01-002  1          1          4              German tranlation option3
1.1.01-002  2          1          5             German tranlation option2
1.1.01-002  3          1          6             German tranlation option1
1.1.01-003  1          1          7             German tranlation option3
1.1.01-003  2          1          8             German tranlation option2
1.1.01-003  3          0          9             German tranlation option1
1.1.01-012  1          1          10             German tranlation option3
1.1.01-012  2          1          11             German tranlation option2
1.1.01-012  3          1          12             German tranlation option1
1.1.01-101  1          1          13             German tranlation option3
1.1.01-101  2          1          14             German tranlation option2
```

**My desired output should look like**

```py
idx               option_de                       option_eng           option_urdu
1.1.01-001  German tranlation option3   This is english of option3  This is urdu of option3
1.1.01-001  German tranlation option2   This is english of option2  This is urdu of option2
1.1.01-001  German tranlation option1   This is english of option1  This is urdu of option1
1.1.01-002  German tranlation option3   This is english of option3  This is urdu of option3
1.1.01-002  German tranlation option2   This is english of option2  This is urdu of option2
1.1.01-002  German tranlation option1   This is english of option1  This is urdu of option1
1.1.01-003  German tranlation option3   This is english of option3  This is urdu of option3
1.1.01-003  German tranlation option2   This is english of option2  This is urdu of option2
1.1.01-003  German tranlation option1   This is english of option1  This is urdu of option1
1.1.01-012  German tranlation option3     na                                  na
1.1.01-012  German tranlation option2     na                                  na
1.1.01-012  German tranlation option1     na                                  na
1.1.01-101  German tranlation option3     na                                  na
1.1.01-101  German tranlation option2     na                                  na
```

**Note**
Please note that the df2 the German option are sorted inversely like option 3 ,2,1 and in df1 the option_en and option_urdu are in opposite order I want to match them.

**What I have tried?**

I have tried different options.`native.merge(foreign,how='left',left_on='idx',right_on='idx')`

Merged always gives me duplicated rows of idxs of both df (like every idx 3 times)
I have also tries `pd.combine_first` but its changes the orders of  options.

I have tried it with `native['key']=native.groupby(["code"]).cumcount()`

**source code to reproduce it**

```py
Foreigndic={'idx': {0: '1.1.01-001', 1: '1.1.01-001', 2: '1.1.01-001', 3: '1.1.01-002', 4: '1.1.01-002', 5: '1.1.01-002', 6: '1.1.01-003', 7: '1.1.01-003', 8: '1.1.01-004', 9: '1.1.01-004'}, 'option_eng': {0: ' Stopping as a precaution at every crossroads', 1: ' Not insisting on your rights', 2: " Allowing for other people's mistakes", 3: ' Inattentiveness', 4: ' Driving too close behind the vehicle in front', 5: ' Unexpectedly heavy braking', 6: '  respond as soon as possible to probable changes in the road traffic situation', 7: '  attempt to identify the intentions of other road users, as soon as possible', 8: ' - of its braking characteristics', 9: ' - of its manoeuvrability'}, 'option_urdu': {0: 'احتیاط کے طور پر ہر دوراہے پر رکنا', 1: 'اپنے حقوق پر اصرار نہیں کرنا', 2: 'دوسرے لوگوں کی غلطیوں کی اجازت دینا', 3: 'غفلت', 4: 'اگلی گاڑی سے مناسب فاصلہ نہ رکھنا', 5: 'غیر متوقع طور پر اگلی گاڑی کا اچانک بریک لگا دینا', 6: 'سڑک پر موجود ٹریفک کی صورتحال میں ممکنہ تبدیلیوں کا جلد سے جلد جواب دینا', 7: 'جتنی جلدی ممکن ہو سڑک کے دوسرے صارفین کے ارادوں کی نشاندہی کرنے کی کوشش کریں', 8: ' اس کی بریک خصوصیات', 9: 'اس کے سسٹم کی جانکاری'}}
Nativedict={'code': {0: 1, 1: 2, 2: 3, 3: 1, 4: 2, 5: 3, 6: 1, 7: 2, 8: 3, 9: 1, 10: 2, 11: 3, 12: 1, 13: 2, 14: 3}, 'ans_id': {0: 1, 1: 2, 2: 3, 3: 4, 4: 5, 5: 6, 6: 7, 7: 8, 8: 9, 9: 10, 10: 11, 11: 12, 12: 13, 13: 14, 14: 15}, 'iscorrect': {0: 1, 1: 1, 2: 0, 3: 1, 4: 1, 5: 1, 6: 1, 7: 1, 8: 0, 9: 1, 10: 1, 11: 1, 12: 1, 13: 1, 14: 1}, 'ans_id_txt': {0: 1, 1: 2, 2: 3, 3: 4, 4: 5, 5: 6, 6: 7, 7: 8, 8: 9, 9: 10, 10: 11, 11: 12, 12: 13, 13: 14, 14: 15}, 'text': {0: 'Nicht auf dem eigenen Recht bestehen', 1: 'Mit Fehlern anderer rechnen', 2: 'Vorsorglich an jeder Kreuzung anhalten', 3: 'Unerwartet starkes Bremsen', 4: 'Unaufmerksamkeit', 5: 'Zu dichtes Auffahren', 6: 'Ich reagiere möglichst frühzeitig auf wahrscheinliche Veränderungen der Verkehrssituation', 7: 'Ich versuche, die Absichten anderer Verkehrsteilnehmer möglichst frühzeitig zu erkennen', 8: 'Ich beschränke die Verkehrsbeobachtung möglichst auf das direkt vor mir fahrende Fahrzeug', 9: 'Ich weiß möglicherweise zu wenig über die Besonderheiten in der Anordnung und der Funktion der Bedienelemente', 10: 'Ich weiß möglicherweise zu wenig über die Besonderheiten im Bremsverhalten', 11: 'Ich weiß möglicherweise zu wenig über die Besonderheiten im Lenkverhalten', 12: 'Der Vorausfahrende bremst unerwartet', 13: 'Der Vorausfahrende betätigt den Blinker vor dem Abbiegen zu spät', 14: 'Der Vorausfahrende hält unerwartet an, um nach dem Weg zu fragen'}, 'ques_id': {0: 1, 1: 1, 2: 1, 3: 2, 4: 2, 5: 2, 6: 3, 7: 3, 8: 3, 9: 4, 10: 4, 11: 4, 12: 5, 13: 5, 14: 5}, 'idx': {0: '1.1.01-001', 1: '1.1.01-001', 2: '1.1.01-001', 3: '1.1.01-002', 4: '1.1.01-002', 5: '1.1.01-002', 6: '1.1.01-003', 7: '1.1.01-003', 8: '1.1.01-003', 9: '1.1.01-004', 10: '1.1.01-004', 11: '1.1.01-004', 12: '1.1.01-101', 13: '1.1.01-101', 14: '1.1.01-101'}}
```

Comment: if you want to merge without duplicates you'll need to eliminate dulicates in one of the dataframes OR merge on more keys to create a unique row per key.

Comment: The problem is, that it is unclear which foreign // native row pair is valid. In your expected output it seems like there is only 1 allowed valid pair possible. But from you provided data it is imposible to determine, how this pairing works.

Comment: I think this is a dupe of [Pandas Merge 101](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53645882/pandas-merging-101) imo.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try creating a unique index for each idx group by adding an order element. Then merge together on the idx and the order column.

```py
import pandas as pd

foreign = pd.DataFrame({'idx': {0: '1.1.01-001', 1: '1.1.01-001',
                                2: '1.1.01-001', 3: '1.1.01-002',
                                4: '1.1.01-002', 5: '1.1.01-002',
                                6: '1.1.01-003', 7: '1.1.01-003',
                                8: '1.1.01-004', 9: '1.1.01-004'},
                        'option_eng': {
                            0: ' Stopping as a precaution at every crossroads',
                            1: ' Not insisting on your rights',
                            2: " Allowing for other people's mistakes",
                            3: ' Inattentiveness',
                            4: ' Driving too close behind the vehicle in front',
                            5: ' Unexpectedly heavy braking',
                            6: '  respond as soon as possible to probable changes in the road traffic situation',
                            7: '  attempt to identify the intentions of other road users, as soon as possible',
                            8: ' - of its braking characteristics',
                            9: ' - of its manoeuvrability'
                        },
                        'option_urdu': {
                            0: 'احتیاط کے طور پر ہر دوراہے پر رکنا',
                            1: 'اپنے حقوق پر اصرار نہیں کرنا',
                            2: 'دوسرے لوگوں کی غلطیوں کی اجازت دینا',
                            3: 'غفلت',
                            4: 'اگلی گاڑی سے مناسب فاصلہ نہ رکھنا',
                            5: 'غیر متوقع طور پر اگلی گاڑی کا اچانک بریک لگا دینا',
                            6: 'سڑک پر موجود ٹریفک کی صورتحال میں ممکنہ تبدیلیوں کا جلد سے جلد جواب دینا',
                            7: 'جتنی جلدی ممکن ہو سڑک کے دوسرے صارفین کے ارادوں کی نشاندہی کرنے کی کوشش کریں',
                            8: ' اس کی بریک خصوصیات',
                            9: 'اس کے سسٹم کی جانکاری'}
                        })

native = pd.DataFrame(
    {'code': {0: 1, 1: 2, 2: 3, 3: 1, 4: 2, 5: 3, 6: 1, 7: 2,
              8: 3, 9: 1, 10: 2, 11: 3, 12: 1, 13: 2, 14: 3},
     'ans_id': {0: 1, 1: 2, 2: 3, 3: 4, 4: 5, 5: 6, 6: 7, 7: 8,
                8: 9, 9: 10, 10: 11, 11: 12, 12: 13, 13: 14, 14: 15},
     'iscorrect': {0: 1, 1: 1, 2: 0, 3: 1, 4: 1, 5: 1, 6: 1, 7: 1,
                   8: 0, 9: 1, 10: 1, 11: 1, 12: 1, 13: 1, 14: 1},
     'ans_id_txt': {0: 1, 1: 2, 2: 3, 3: 4, 4: 5, 5: 6, 6: 7, 7: 8,
                    8: 9, 9: 10, 10: 11, 11: 12, 12: 13, 13: 14,
                    14: 15},
     'text': {0: 'Nicht auf dem eigenen Recht bestehen',
              1: 'Mit Fehlern anderer rechnen',
              2: 'Vorsorglich an jeder Kreuzung anhalten',
              3: 'Unerwartet starkes Bremsen',
              4: 'Unaufmerksamkeit',
              5: 'Zu dichtes Auffahren',
              6: 'Ich reagiere möglichst frühzeitig auf '
                 'wahrscheinliche Veränderungen der Verkehrssituation',
              7: 'Ich versuche, die Absichten anderer '
                 'Verkehrsteilnehmer möglichst frühzeitig zu erkennen',
              8: 'Ich beschränke die Verkehrsbeobachtung '
                 'möglichst auf das direkt vor mir fahrende Fahrzeug',
              9: 'Ich weiß möglicherweise zu wenig über die Besonderheiten '
                 'in der Anordnung und der Funktion der Bedienelemente',
              10: 'Ich weiß möglicherweise zu wenig über '
                  'die Besonderheiten im Bremsverhalten',
              11: 'Ich weiß möglicherweise zu wenig über '
                  'die Besonderheiten im Lenkverhalten',
              12: 'Der Vorausfahrende bremst unerwartet',
              13: 'Der Vorausfahrende betätigt den Blinker vor dem Abbiegen zu spät',
              14: 'Der Vorausfahrende hält unerwartet an, um nach dem Weg zu fragen'},
     'ques_id': {0: 1, 1: 1, 2: 1, 3: 2, 4: 2, 5: 2, 6: 3, 7: 3,
                 8: 3, 9: 4, 10: 4, 11: 4, 12: 5, 13: 5, 14: 5},
     'idx': {0: '1.1.01-001', 1: '1.1.01-001', 2: '1.1.01-001',
             3: '1.1.01-002', 4: '1.1.01-002', 5: '1.1.01-002',
             6: '1.1.01-003', 7: '1.1.01-003', 8: '1.1.01-003',
             9: '1.1.01-004', 10: '1.1.01-004', 11: '1.1.01-004',
             12: '1.1.01-101', 13: '1.1.01-101', 14: '1.1.01-101'}}
)

# Grab Columns and add key for group order (level_1)
foreign = foreign[['idx', 'option_eng', 'option_urdu']].groupby('idx') \
    .apply(lambda x: x.reset_index(drop=True)) \
    .drop(columns=['idx']) \
    .reset_index()
native = native[['idx', 'text']].groupby('idx') \
    .apply(lambda x: x.reset_index(drop=True)) \
    .drop(columns=['idx']) \
    .reset_index()

# Merge Together on idx and level_1
merged = native.merge(foreign, on=['idx', 'level_1'], how='outer') \
    .drop(columns='level_1') \
    .fillna('na')

print(merged.to_string(index=False))
```

| idx | text | option_eng | option_urdu |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1.1.01-001 | Nicht auf dem eigenen Recht bestehen | Stopping as a precaution at every crossroads | احتیاط کے طور پر ہر دوراہے پر رکنا |
| 1.1.01-001 | Mit Fehlern anderer rechnen | Not insisting on your rights | اپنے حقوق پر اصرار نہیں کرنا |
| 1.1.01-001 | Vorsorglich an jeder Kreuzung anhalten | Allowing for other people's mistakes | دوسرے لوگوں کی غلطیوں کی اجازت دینا |
| 1.1.01-002 | Unerwartet starkes Bremsen | Inattentiveness | غفلت |
| 1.1.01-002 | Unaufmerksamkeit | Driving too close behind the vehicle in front | اگلی گاڑی سے مناسب فاصلہ نہ رکھنا |
| 1.1.01-002 | Zu dichtes Auffahren | Unexpectedly heavy braking | غیر متوقع طور پر اگلی گاڑی کا اچانک بریک لگا دینا |
| 1.1.01-003 | Ich reagiere möglichst frühzeitig auf wahrscheinliche Veränderungen der Verkehrssituation | respond as soon as possible to probable changes in the road traffic situation | سڑک پر موجود ٹریفک کی صورتحال میں ممکنہ تبدیلیوں کا جلد سے جلد جواب دینا |
| 1.1.01-003 | Ich versuche, die Absichten anderer Verkehrsteilnehmer möglichst frühzeitig zu erkennen | attempt to identify the intentions of other road users, as soon as possible | جتنی جلدی ممکن ہو سڑک کے دوسرے صارفین کے ارادوں کی نشاندہی کرنے کی کوشش کریں |
| 1.1.01-003 | Ich beschränke die Verkehrsbeobachtung möglichst auf das direkt vor mir fahrende Fahrzeug | na | na |
| 1.1.01-004 | Ich weiß möglicherweise zu wenig über die Besonderheiten in der Anordnung und der Funktion der Bedienelemente | - of its braking characteristics | اس کی بریک خصوصیات |
| 1.1.01-004 | Ich weiß möglicherweise zu wenig über die Besonderheiten im Bremsverhalten | - of its manoeuvrability | اس کے سسٹم کی جانکاری |
| 1.1.01-004 | Ich weiß möglicherweise zu wenig über die Besonderheiten im Lenkverhalten | na | na |
| 1.1.01-101 | Der Vorausfahrende bremst unerwartet | na | na |
| 1.1.01-101 | Der Vorausfahrende betätigt den Blinker vor dem Abbiegen zu spät | na | na |
| 1.1.01-101 | Der Vorausfahrende hält unerwartet an, um nach dem Weg zu fragen | na | na |

---

Aside: Your provided data does not appear to align correctly. Foreign: `1.1.01-002,0,Inattentiveness` is the first row of the 1.1.01-002 group, but that aligns with Native: `1.1.01-002,0,Unerwartet starkes Bremsen` which is incorrect. It should align with the second row `1.1.01-002,1,Unaufmerksamkeit`. But assuming you have translations in the correct order in both tables this should work.

Comment: Yes Actually that is the problem. We can change the order with `code` that is `sort_code` 1,2,3, but I need to inverse it to match it with `eng` and `Urdu translation` I have use this method to rearrange . `native['key']=native.groupby(["code"]).cumcount()
#print(native.head(100))
#native= native.sort_values(['key','code'],ascending=[True,False]).drop('key',1)#.reset_index()` the problem is when I merge it automatically change the order

Comment: The alignment is still not consistent. For group `1.1.01-001` the mapping from `native` to `foreign` is 0 -> 1, 1 -> 0, 2 -> 2. That seems like you have some kind of rotation in `foreign`.  But `1.1.01-002` the mapping is 0 -> 0, 1-> 2, 2 -> 1. Which is a different kind of rotation in `foreign`.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming that you don't need to sort the tables, `pd.concat()` with `axis=1` as an argument will do the trick.

```
pd.concat([
    native[['idx', 'option_de']], 
    foreign[['option_eng', 'option_urdu']]
], axis=1)
```

**That worked for me**

```
native['key']=native.groupby(["code"]).cumcount()
native= native.sort_values(['key','code'],ascending=[True,False]).drop('key',1).reset_index()

native=native.rename(columns={'idx.1':'idx'})
mrg=pd.concat([native[['idx', 'text','iscorrect']],foreign[['option_eng', 'option_urdu']]], axis=1)
```

Comment: In this way the order of matching index cannot be preserved. It is just blink addition of two extra columns, but I want to match based on index that is common in both dfs